# Instantiate sub module according to input value

Tags: verilog

I want to instantiate a sub module according to input value but this seems impossible.

I tried these methods:

method 1: always @ -> cannot instantiate sub modules there.

method 2: generate -> gives input is not constant error.

here is the code

```
module traffic_lights_top(Clk,
                          SN_CI, WE_CI,
                          SN_PI, WE_PI,
                          SN_CL, WE_CL,
                          SN_PL, WE_PL,
                          SN_TJ, WE_TJ,
                          Count);

     input Clk;
     input SN_CI, WE_CI;
     input SN_PI, WE_PI;
     input[3:0] SN_TJ, WE_TJ;
     output[2:0] SN_CL, WE_CL;
     output[2:0] SN_PL, WE_PL;
     output[6:0] Count;

                                // 15                   // 19                       // 34                       // 38               
     parameter SEC1_nt = 7'b0001111, SEC2_nt = 7'b0010011, SEC3_nt = 7'b0100010, SEC4_nt = 7'b0100110; // time for each light in non traffic times
                                // 30              // 38                    // 68                   // 76
     parameter SEC1_t = 7'b0011110, SEC2_t = 7'b0100110, SEC3_t = 7'b1000100, SEC4_t = 7'b1001100; // time for each light in traffic times

     //traffic t1(Clk,SN_CI,WE_CI,SN_PI,WE_PI,SN_CL,WE_CL,SN_PL,WE_PL,Count);

     generate
        case({SN_TJ, WE_TJ})
            {4'b1111,4'b0000}:
                begin
                    traffic SN_t(Clk,SN_CI,WE_CI,SN_PI,WE_PI,SN_CL,WE_CL,SN_PL,WE_PL,Count);
                    defparam SN_t.SEC1 = 7'b0000000;
                    defparam SN_t.SEC2 = SEC2_t;
                    defparam SN_t.SEC3 = SEC3_nt;
                    defparam SN_t.SEC4 = SEC4_nt;
                end

            {4'b0000,4'b1111}:
                begin
                    traffic WE_t(Clk,SN_CI,WE_CI,SN_PI,WE_PI,SN_CL,WE_CL,SN_PL,WE_PL,Count);
                    defparam WE_t.SEC1=SEC1_nt;
                    defparam WE_t.SEC2=SEC2_nt;
                    defparam WE_t.SEC3=SEC3_t;
                    defparam WE_t.SEC4=SEC4_t;
                end

            default:
                begin
                    traffic same_t(Clk,SN_CI,WE_CI,SN_PI,WE_PI,SN_CL,WE_CL,SN_PL,WE_PL,Count);
                    defparam same_t.SEC1=SEC1_nt;
                    defparam same_t.SEC2=SEC2_nt;
                    defparam same_t.SEC3=SEC3_nt;
                    defparam same_t.SEC4=SEC4_nt;
                end
        endcase
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

SEC1_t, ... representing there is traffic

Sec1_nt, ... representing there is no traffic

Is there any way to fix this or I must change my approach?

Comment: If traffic(sub module) is needed I can add that too, but I don't think so.

Comment: Consider what you're asking for here. You want some circuit to pop in and out of existence depending on the voltage on some input wire. Does that sound like a reasonable expectation when you stop and think about it?

Comment: Yes. For example, you might just intantiate 127 modules, and have an enable input which you set for only the first N of them depending on the signal inputs. Without knowing more what you're trying to do, I can't say whether this is a reasonable thing to do or ridiculously inefficient.

Comment: Sounds great way I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not how Verilog works. Verilog is a **hardware description language**. You don't create new hardware based on input values. You specify the hardware that you need and its **behavior** changes based on input values.

Similarly, all of the parameters needed to define the hardware must be known at synthesis (compile) time. Loops that generate hardware must have a known number of iterations. This is just how hardware synthesis works.